# SQL Server need top 1 record for one column and all other records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to have one query for to select all records of `KitchenBlinkSound='Y'` plus `top 1` of `KitchenBlinkSound='N'`, here is my table structure.

[image]

And my requested result will be `OrderNo 225,226,227`. Basically it contains all `KitchenBlinkSound='Y'` records plus `top 1` of  `KitchenBlinkSound='N'` record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE KitchenBlinkSound='Y'
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM TABLE WHERE KitchenBlinkSound='N'
ORDER BY ORDERNO
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM #TABLE1 WHERE KitchenBlinkSound='Y'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ORDERNO,KITCHENSTATUS,KitchenBlinkSound FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KitchenBlinkSound ORDER BY ORDERNO ASC) RNO 
        FROM #TABLE1 WHERE KitchenBlinkSound='N'
    )TAB
    WHERE TAB.RNO=1
)MAIN
```

- As sub-queries doesn't allow `ORDER BY`, ROW_NUMBER() is added in order to make sure that you are selecting the `TOP 1` `ORDERNO` in ascending order. If you want to take in descending order change `ASC` to `DESC`.

Comment: what if i need `ORDER BY OrderNo desc`

Comment: ORDER BY OrderNo desc will bring OrderNo - 230 as the Top 1 item. By default ORDER BY ORDERNO will bring OrderNo - 227 as the Top 1 item. @Purvesh Desai

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from [your table name] where KitchenBlickSound = 'Y'
UNION
Select TOP 1 * from [your table name] where KitchenBlickSound = 'N'
```